# Import CSV command not working on Azure CM Server

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am using below `Powershell command` to read CSV file from directory:

```
$importData = Import-CSV "C:\Projects\news_sample.csv"
```

It's working fine on my local Sitecore instance and machine. I am running the same script on `Azure CM instance` and it's not working and throwing the error `Directory not found.`

Can anyone please let me know, how can I get the server path, I have put the CSV files on the Server using Filezilla but not able to determine the server path? Is there any Powershell command the same as `Server.MapPath("~path")` in C#?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PowerShell you can use the `Sitecore.IO.FileUtil.MapPath` method to get your path:

```
$folder = [Sitecore.IO.FileUtil]::MapPath("~/path")
$importData = Import-CSV "$($folder)/news_sample.csv"
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Richard, it's solved my issue.